# when going back and forth from an activity which shows an image, will get memory error. not freeing image?

Tags: java, android, image

I have an activity which is called.  This activity will show an image.  The issue is that if i go to the previous activity within the same application and then recall it.  If i do it enough times, i will get a memory error.  Is there a way to make it so that it will free up that space when you go back/end the activity?

I thought it freed automatically, but maybe it doesnt ?  Is there a call that I should be doing?  Like onDestroy(){  image.recycle(); } and all that such stuff?

I figure there is something going on here.

**Exception**

```
10-16 11:50:27.778: E/AndroidRuntime(18255): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 11:50:27.778: E/AndroidRuntime(18255): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-16 11:50:27.778: E/AndroidRuntime(18255):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
10-16 11:50:27.778: E/AndroidRuntime(18255):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:530)
10-16 11:50:27.778: E/AndroidRuntime(18255):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:299)
10-16 11:50:27.778: E/AndroidRuntime(18255):    at com.bentley.cordova.plugins.ZoomImageActivity$1.run(ZoomImageActivity.java:111)
10-16 11:50:27.778: E/AndroidRuntime(18255):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-16 11:50:27.778: E/AndroidRuntime(18255):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-16 11:50:27.778: E/AndroidRuntime(18255):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-16 11:50:27.778: E/AndroidRuntime(18255):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)
10-16 11:50:27.778: E/AndroidRuntime(18255):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 11:50:27.778: E/AndroidRuntime(18255):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-16 11:50:27.778: E/AndroidRuntime(18255):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
10-16 11:50:27.778: E/AndroidRuntime(18255):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
10-16 11:50:27.778: E/AndroidRuntime(18255):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: it would probably help to see the specific exception, and also perhaps some of your code...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem and solved it thanks to another stackoverflow user. I don't find the answer, so I'll post it here:

if your layout looks something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/yourcontainer"
...>

more objects

</LinearLayout>
```

In your onDestroy method, you should unbind all the drawables like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.yourcontainer));
}

private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view == null)
        return;
    if (view.getBackground() != null)
    view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
    }
    try {
        ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException mayHappen) {
        Log.e("Error:", mayHappen.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would it go in onDestroy, or something else, like onStop() ?

Comment: I have it in the onDestroy event. Remember to pass the right view to unbindDrawables!
You could also release the bitmap memory manually by calling yourView.getBackground().setCallback(null)

Comment: your instanceof command throws an error.... saying "incompatible conditional operated between view and viewgroup"   nvm, forgot to import it. lol,

Comment: i think the view i was passing in was the ROOT LINEAR LAYOUT.  Is that not correct? Or should i just do the ImageView?

Comment: If you use the unbindDrawables method, you should pass it the root layout. Doesn't matter if its Linear, Frame, Relative or whatever ;)

Comment: that seems to not be working.  When i click the return button, is onDestroy called?  For some reason i thought onDestroy was called only when the application ended, and not a single activity within an application

Comment: i tried a bunch of different ways.  onStop(), onDestroy() and whenever the activity is recalled, it gets the memory error.  Is there something else you or I are missing?

Comment: scaled down image taken with an 8meg pixel camera.

Comment: you should be able to see the size of the image! 8mp camera can take up to 8x2^10x24 Bytes! that's a lot of memory...

Comment: it is going Memory out of bounds on a 31961104-byte allocation for that image.  That is 31,961,104 byetes or ~ 32Meg allocation.  Do you know how i would scale it down more?  Right now, i set the sameple size to 4.

Comment: there is the problem... it is a huge image!! You should post a new question now ;)

Comment: i noticed it crashes on the line:   image.decodeFile(_path,opts);  It isnt assigned to anything.... as i was using it to get dimensions of it, to see how much i should scale it.  Maybe it doesnt like that.